# Actionscript ExternalInterface IE Intermittent Failure

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a Facebook app which is working fine in all browsers except IE where it works sometimes and fails at other times. I'm using ExternalInterface to work with the Facebook Javascript API. It seems my callbacks are being set to null on an intermittent basis in IE. For example, when I open the Invite Friends pop up:

```
function inviteFriends(messageText) {
  FB.ui({
        method : 'apprequests',
        message : messageText
        }, function(response) {
                console.log("onInviteFriendsComplete: " + getFlashObject().onInviteFriendsComplete);
               if (response && !response.error)
                   getFlashObject().onInviteFriendsComplete(true);
              else
                  getFlashObject().onInviteFriendsComplete(false);
       });
}
```

This works fine sometimes. The console log traces:

```
onInviteFriendsComplete: function () { 
     return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));
   }
```

When the application fails it traces:

```
onInviteFriendsComplete: null
```

The debugger throws an object expected error when the callback is null.

This issue occurs intermittently with other requests as well:

```
function purchaseItem(packHTML) {
  FB.ui({
        method : 'pay',
        action : 'purchaseitem',
        product : packHTML
        }, function(response) {
               console.log("onPurchaseItemComplete: " + getFlashObject().onPurchaseItemComplete);
               try {
                    getFlashObject().onPurchaseItemComplete(response, packHTML);
              } catch(e) {
                    console.log("getFlashObject: " + getFlashObject());
                    console.log("Flash top: " + getFlashObject().style.top);
                    console.log("Flash visibility: " + getFlashObject().style.visibility);
             }
       });
}
```

When the callback fails the log (from the catch statement) shows that the Flash object is found and not null. The style shows its top at 0px and visibility is hidden. I am intercepting the hideFlashCallback:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  // init the FB JS SDK
          FB.init({
         appId : facebookAppId, // App ID from the app dashboard
                    channelUrl : 'channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
                    status : true, // Check Facebook Login status
                    cookie : true,
                    xfbml : true, // Look for social plugins on the page
                    hideFlashCallback : onFlashHide
          });
          isFacebookInitialized = true;
};



function onFlashHide(params) {
  console.log(getFlashObject() == params.elem);
  if (params.state == 'opened') {
  displayFlashScreenshot();
  } else {
  hideFlashScreenshot();
  }
}




function displayFlashScreenshot() {
  // Call the Flash ActionScript method to create the dynamic screenshot data
          var flashObject = getFlashObject();
          var screenshotData = flashObject.exportScreenshot();

          if (screenshotData != null) {
  // Set the screenshot image data as a base64 encoded data URI in the img src attribute
  document.getElementById('screenshotObject').src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + screenshotData;

  // Set the screenshot img dimensions to match the Flash object tag.
                    document.getElementById('screenshotObject').width = flashObject.width;
                    document.getElementById('screenshotObject').height = flashObject.height;

document.getElementById('imageContent').style.visibility = 'visible';

          }
}



function hideFlashScreenshot() {
   document.getElementById('imageContent').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

I'm using Starling so I've set the wmode to direct. Facebook is hiding and showing the Flash object and I'm just drawing the currect state of the app's UI into the 'imageContent' element.

When the callback is shown as null the Flash object remains hidden.

I hope someone can help as I'm about three full days into this one issue with no resolution in sight.

Comment: I think you have a context issue somewhere but no way to tell since getFlashObject() code is not posted. Also you might want to use SWFObject to embed your flash and use jQuery for all your html manipulations.